# Box2D/Farseer Collision Detection

Tags: box2d, farseer-physics-engine

I am looking for literature - or a simple explanation - on how the Farseer (and for that reason, the Box2D) collision detection system works - specifically the logic that comes **after** the broadphase culling:

- What data structure does it use?
- How does it use that data structure to determine if a collision has occurred?
- How does it calculate the response normals?

**NB:** I am not asking how to use it, I merely want to know how it works as a matter of personal enlightenment.

Comment: Add a bounty and post the link to question on Farseer/Box2D boards.

Comment: Have you considered jumping into the source and checking it out?

Comment: @Drackir I definitely have been looking at the code - but it's hard to get started when I don't know what I am actually looking at :). Really; I am just look for a broad overview so that I have it at the back of my mind while reading the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [small explanation](http://www.farseergames.com/storage/farseerphysics/Manual2.1.htm#_Toc211622630) of the Farseer 2.1 physics. It includes information on both SAT and Distance Grid detection.

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend [Real-Time Collision Detection by Christer Ericson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1558607323)

It'll answer all your questions, go buy, rent, steal this book.

Comment: It's worth noting, that this book covers 3D collision detection, whereas box2d and farseer are 2D.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll avoid stealing it at all costs :).